# How to optimize animated gif by using client-side JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, gif

Or, is it possible?

Like when user uploads some animated gif (not actually upload, just select them from local machine to browser), then use some JavaScript to do:

- Color Reduction
- Lossy GIF compression
- Drop some middle frames
- Resize
- ..etc

Comment: Yes, It is very much possible. Read more about [`HTML5 Canvas`](http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/tutorials/html5-canvas-element/) and you will get how to achieve that..

Comment: You can [load and display frames on a canvas.](https://jnordberg.github.io/gif.js/tests/canvas.html) Then you can [work with each frame's image data](http://camanjs.com/guides/#AdvancedUsage) from canvas.

Comment: @RayonDabre Canvas drawImage should only draw the first frame of any animated image. So for animated gif, no, it's not so simple. But still feasible.

Comment: @Kaiido, I agree with you. It is not so simple..

Comment: You can fetch the individual image frames from the original .gif with [this script](https://github.com/shachaf/jsgif). Then you can use canvas pixel manipulation, canvas transformations and re-encoding options in [this script mentioned by S.D.](https://github.com/jnordberg/gif.js) or [this script](https://github.com/antimatter15/jsgif) to create your modified .gif.